# How to swap two values in a column against all records in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Recently an interviewer asked me a question where there was a Table employee having a column as employment_type having only two values viz. 'Permanent' & 'Contractor'. Now we come across a scenario where we found due to a bug we have entered 'Contractor' in the records where we should have entered 'Permanent' and the same applies for the records having the value as 'Permanent'.

My solution was to write a PL-SQL stored procedure & get both the different sets maybe in a cursor and make the update and finally do the DB refresh.

However, the expectation was in the form of single SQL query. I tried different combinations of nesting up the query no luck. Can anyone help me with this query.

The primary key of this table was Employee_ID.

Answer (score 3):

Gag!  Don't use a cursor if there is a set-based solution:

```
update employee
    set employment_type = (case when status = 'Permanent' then 'Contract' else 'Permanent' end)
    where employment_type in ('Permanent', 'Contract');
```